# Change Excel Checkbox text color when checked

Tags: excel, vba

How can I change the text color of a ActiveX Checkbox when checked?
Can I also change the color of the check mark?

Comment: Because [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)
 please incude in your question: ⓐ What you have tried so far, ⓑ what you have researched so far.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
CheckBox1.ForeColor = vbRed
Else: CheckBox1.ForeColor = vbBlack
End If
End Sub
```

But i still don't know how to chage the color of the check mark.

Comment: As far as I know the standard ActiveX checkbox control is not able to change the color of the check mark.